# Z function for factorial in C

Tags: c

I came across a question online - to find the Z function of the factorial of t nos (no of zeroes at the lsb end of the factorial)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int x)
{
    if(x==1)
        return 1;
    else
    return (x*fact(x-1));
}
int main()
{
    int t,n,k,c;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        k=fact(n);
        c=0;
        while(k%10==0)
        {
            k/=10;
            c++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program I made, but it's too slow. How can I do this faster?

Comment: Are you aware that anything beyond 12! will not fit into an int? That your program is slow is the least of your problems. The problem asks you to go about this problem differently. (Hint: Each time that you multiply by 10 or when you multiply by 5 after multiplying with 2, you add a zero to the end. The first factorial with a trailing 0 is 5!, the first one with two trailing zeros is 10!. Beware: 25! has six trailing zeros, not only five.))

Comment: Maybe you should go to Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I forgot about that. Anyways I solved it by counting n/(5^k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I can think of two possible solutions at the first glance.

- change the recursive loop into an iterative loop
- use memoization to speed up calculation of already known function values (basically it works like a cache)

Memoization technique can speed up the calculation significantly, though at the cost of usage of memory.
If I were you I'd do the memoization. I am very confident your code will run faster, since it is a simple factorial function (actually a classic example for memoization, like the Fibonacci numbers).